# While never ends with random number

Tags: c, random, while-loop

I am trying to get a random number and have the while end if its over another number:

```
int main() // random
{
    int x= 50;
    int i;

    while (i>x){
        srand(time(0));
        int i = rand() %100;
        printf("laenge %d", i);
    }
}
```

The while starts well and generates different numbers (like 1.000 times 11, 1.000 times 75...) but it never ends.

I have 2 questions, why does it not end? 
And why does it get in the console 1.000 times the same random number and then 1.000 times the next one?

If I add:

```
int main() // random
{
    int x= 50;
    int i;

    while (i>x){
        srand(time(0));
        int i = rand() %100;
        printf("laenge %d", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Sleep(1); the whole code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: In addition to other answers, you should initialise `i` with a value.

Comment: +1 for providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Fabian, the `int i = rand()%100` is shadowing the outer declaration of `int i`. If you replace it for `i = rand() % 100` your first fragment will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You redeclare `i` here:

```
int i = rand() %100;
^^^
```

so it is a different `i` then the one use to check the *while loop* here:

```
while (i>x){
```

this also means you need initialize `i` in the first declaration since using an uninitialized variable is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You only should call `srand` once, so move it outside the loop. Also it would be a good idea to read [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) from the *C FAQ*. The recommended formula for generating a random *integer* in the range `[M, N]` is:

```
M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)
```

which in your case would be:

```
rand() / (RAND_MAX / (100 + 1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are seeding the random number generator inside the loop with the time in seconds as a seed. This resets the random number generator, so it will always return the same number until `time(0)` returns a different value (i.e., a second has passed). Move the seeding outside the loop.

Also remove the `int` from `int i` inside the loop, otherwise you will have a different `i` inside the loop than the one you are checking in the loop condition, which causes the loop to never end since the `i` in `i > x` is never changed.

And, finally, initialize `i` so that it will have a known value when the loop first starts. (Or change the loop to `do`-`while` so that the condition is at the end.)

```
int x = 50;
int i = 51; // <- initialize

srand(time(0)); // <- seed outside loop
while (i > x) {
    i = rand() %100; // <- use the same 'i' inside and outside loop
    printf("laenge %d", i);
}
```

Comment: But on this, the while also never ends?

Comment: @FabianBoulegue It never ends because the `i` in the condition is never assigned to, because you have a new `int i` inside the loop. Remove the `int` as per the code in my answer.

Comment: ah ok :) thanks, does you also have a idea for:
And why does i get in the console 1.000 times the same random number and then 1.000 times the next one?

Comment: @FabianBoulegue Because you are seeding the random number generator with the same seed for 1 second. Move the `srand` outside the loop, as per the code in my answer.

Comment: ok i see, is this the "a good way" to generate random numbers in c?

Comment: @FabianBoulegue For casual (non-cryptographic) use `rand` is fine. Just remember to seed it with `srand` only once (or when you wish to reset it). For producing numbers from 0 to 99 using `% 100` may not be the best option from a perspective of randomness, but that, I think, is outside the scope of this question and unlikely to matter in this kind of use.

Comment: @FabianBoulegue I added a link to a C FAQ question in my answer which covers the good ways to generate random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are seeding each time with almost the same number: `time(0)` will return the same number for about a thousand loops before being updated.

Solution: remove the `srand(time(0))` from your loop and put it before the `while()`.